# How to prevent clear full row selection mode when click the cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

If i select Full row, its getting selected at the same time i click my cursor to another cell, full row selection cleared. But i don't want to clear the full row selection. Selected full row should not clear.

Help me please.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear.

Comment: How can i select full row and also select next row of one cell in datagridview??, Here the cell selection no need to highlight only selected full row should highlight... Windows application

Answer (score 1):

If `Tablix` `.Multiselect` property is set to `True` you can select multiple rows by pressing `CTRL` (multiple non-continuous rows) or `SHIFT` (multiple continuous rows). Selection in `DataGridView` works like in Excel so you could also use `CTRL+SHIFT+END` to select every rows from current row to last row.